# getting error Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to pass a string to a function

Tags: c

When I try to pass the current time as a string to the function logger in my code I get an error saying that "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". but when I put `static char str[30]` the error doesn't come. but with no errors the resulting file makes impossible to open it.

```
void logger(char * logType, int loggingLevel, char * massage)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%s|%d|%s|%s",logType,loggingLevel,massage,currentTime());
    fclose(fp);   
}

char * currentTime(void)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    char str[30];
    char *string;
    struct tm * timeInfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeInfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(str, 26, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", timeInfo);
    return str;

}
```

so previously I made the currentTime function like this

```
char * currentTime(void) {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    return asctime(timeinfo);
}
```

it works fine but that is not the way I need to display the time.

Comment: char str[30] is local, it became unusable after exit of the function. Any usage of a function result like this will result in a crash.

Comment: thats why after that i used "static char" as ive mentioned above. so it won't be a problem then

Comment: @Laksith - If you use a static buffer you will get other problems later. In a multi-threaded program, several threads could call the function at the same time and would all get the same buffer. Not good either!

Comment: thanks. and i heard that from a friend too. he said its better to use Malloc() set memory and remove when needed. something like that. Is it possible. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a local variable from function `currentTime()` which is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change function signature to: `char * currentTime(char *inputBuffer, size_t bufLen)`

Comment: current time function can’t contain parameters as for this. for my purpose. Could you tell me what is the reason for `(char *inputBuffer, size_t bufLen`

Comment: @Laksith Once your function return, local variable `str` dies. First solution is to use `static` attribute in `str`. But this will make function non-re-entrant. (Not thread safe). Also keeping the return value of such function is not safe as it can change without the knowledge of user. If caller provides the `inputBuffer`, your function would remain thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to a *local* variable (here the `str` buffer) from the `currentTime` function.

You cannot do this, because as soon as local variables goes out of scope (that is when you leave the `currentTime` function), their content is undefined, they will most of the time contain garbage.

Therefore you must declare `str` as static:

```
static char str[30];
```

In that case `str` exists all the time during the execution of your program and not only during the execution of the `currentTime` function.

But this can cause other problems.

Example:

```
char *time1;
char *time2;

time1 = currentTime();
...
/* somewhat later */
time2 = currentTime();

/* now time1 and time2 point to the same memory location     */
/* which contains the current time at the second call        */
```

Or problems when you use threads.

Answer (score 2):

For the reasons exposed in other answers your function is not reentrant meaning that each time you call it the result is overwritten. To create a dedicated instance for each call you can also simply use an `strdup()` to create a duplicate of your string that can be deleted using `free()` after use:

```
void logger(char * logType, int loggingLevel, char * massage)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    char *sTime = currentTime();    //Get the value
    fprintf(fp, "%s|%d|%s|%s",logType,loggingLevel,massage, sTime);
    free(sTime);    //Release the string if no more needed.
    fclose(fp);   
}

char * currentTime(void)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    char str[30];
    struct tm * timeInfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeInfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(str, 26, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", timeInfo);
    return strdup(str);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does char *string ?

Comment: @Michi It's just a typo. I thought to build the string myself using `malloc()`, and I needed it for that, but then I changed my mind and used `strdup()`. But forget to remove it. I have updated the sample.

Comment: I did it . And exactly did what i needed. Including the time it takes. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Laksith Thanks. If it is ok you can accept the answer.